# compilation of sass bootstrap in sails project

Tags: sass, sails.js, bootstrap-sass

I have SailsJs project. And need to install bootstrap-sass version.
I am using `grunt-contrib-sass`. But do I really need ruby installed?
Can I modify grunt, so node-sass will be responsible for compilation?

Answer (score 0):

Following this example: https://github.com/sails101/using-sass

1. Instead of `grunt-contrib-sass`, use `grunt-sass` instead to avoid the Ruby dependency:

   - Yarn: `yarn add grunt-sass`
   - NPM: `npm i --save grunt-sass`
2. Install `bootstrap-sass`:

   - Yarn: `yarn add bootstrap-sass`
   - NPM: `npm i --save bootstrap-sass`
3. Assuming you've followed along with the repo instructions linked above, we need to add `bootstrap-sass` to our imports in the `sass.js` config:

--

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

  grunt.config.set('sass', {
    dev: {
      options: {
        includePaths: ['node_modules/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets']
      },
      files: [{
        expand: true,
        cwd: 'assets/styles/',
        src: ['importer.scss'],
        dest: '.tmp/public/styles/',
        ext: '.css'
      }]
    }
  });

  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-sass');
};
```

4. Now we can simply do `@import "bootstrap"` in our sass.